# Drupal Block with View Titles

Tags: drupal, view

In Drupal7 I have a block showing the title of a view:

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
print $view->human_name;
```

Now I want to do this for all views shown in the content area of the page. I have tried several things but no clue how to make it, as I'm not familiar with php.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hav you tried to edit page.tpl.php?

Comment: The template is not the problem. The problem is the method I need to loop thru all the titles of all views displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to output the title of the current page view.  If that's the case, try this:

```
$view = views_get_page_view();
print $view->human_name;
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_page_view/7

Comment: No - what I'm trying to do is to get the titles of all views which are currently loaded on the displayed page. Thus I would need a method to load the views as an array and then loop thru it. But I havent found anything.